# Haskell : convert Either ParseError a to a

Tags: haskell

I'm actually using Parsec to make an Expression Parser and I have a little question (I'm french also sorry for my english ).

I have this code :

```
data Expression ... -- Recursive type Expression

type Store [(String, Float)] -- variable's storage

type Parser a = Parsec String () a
parseExpr :: [Char] -> Either ParseError Expression
parseExpr string = parse expr "" stream 
    where 
        stream = filter (not . isSpace) string

-- Parser's rules ...

raiseError a = Nothing

evalParser :: [Char] -> Store -> Float
evalParser expr store = fromMaybe 0 (either raiseError (eval store)(parseExpr expr))
```

This code works really well, but i need this function :

```
parseExpression :: String -> Maybe Expression
```

And I have no ideas of the right syntax to use.

Someone can help me please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll start it for you, and you can finish it:

```
eitherToMaybe :: Either a b -> Maybe b
eitherToMaybe (Left a) = ???
eitherToMaybe (Right b) = ???
```

A severe over-generalization looks like this (you can find this function with a less direct implementation in the [`monadplus`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monadplus-1.4.2/docs/Control-Applicative-Alternative.html#v:afold) package):

```
import Control.Applicative (Alternative (..))
import Data.Profunctor.Unsafe ((#.))
import Data.Monoid (Alt (..))

afold :: (Foldable f, Alternative g)
                      => f a -> g a
afold = getAlt . foldMap (Alt #. pure)
```

But you don't really need to get into that business just yet.

Comment: @AdrienVaret, if you're satisfied with the answer, you can click the check mark to accept it.